# How can I later review guides shown at reputation milestones?

Tags: support, privileges, help-center

I want to know how to review guides that were shown to me when I  got a certain reputation. For example:

- how to use '@' sign
- how to flag in posts
- how to edit posts
- how to accept answers

Some things are not shown in the FAQ sections. I don't want to search Meta for answers to questions, I want to review (or re-study.) Is there any way to get this guide again?

Specifically, I don't remember how to reply messages multiple guys by one message. I want to review (re-study) the guide for using `@`. I know if I want to review badges I can use my Notifications. What about for my other privileges?

> UPDATE ( due to toolbar changes )

How can I view my privious privileges on meta site ?

Comment: but I am always try searching before asking questions because I am afraid my question leads to duplicate.

Comment: "... I want to know it because I don't remember how to reply messages multiple guys by one message" is sample problem..

Comment: please don't be aggresive due to my question because I am a new user of its.

Comment: This sentence makes no sense: "if I want to review badges I can use my Notifications. What about for my other privileges?" if you can explain what you mean maybe someone here can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to access guides or help for the Stack Exchange family. If you specifically remember that a particular privilege was related to gaining a level of reputation, you can use these steps to go back to the help for it:

[image: privileges link]

Hover over your name at the top and when the dropdown appears, click on privileges. This will bring you to the Privileges section of the help centre. You can click on a privilege to learn more.

[image: privileges page]

For example clicking on the Comment Everywhere privilege will take you to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment which includes how to use the @ and more.

If you gained the privilege recently, you can also find a link in your Notifications - scroll down:

[image: notifications]

Comment: Yah , This is my answer ! Thanks in advance for your valuable times..

Answer (score 1):

For more technical issues, we have the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions here on Meta which pretty much covers everything, in more detail than the help center or the new user guide.

When in doubt, visit the [faq index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/152859) and search there for what you want to know. For example searching for "comments" lead you quickly to this faq: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/152859) where it's explained you can't messages multiple guys in one comment.